# Is Browser-Update A Legitimate Site?

Tags: malware

I searched this site to find if the following site is legitimate and didn't see any posts.  A legitimate company is linking to this site on their front page with a warning - the site linked to:

`https://browser-update.org/update-browser.html`

From the site - information:

> Browser-update.org is a tool to unobtrusively notify visitors that they should update their web browser in order to use your website.
>
> This is done with care not to annoy, lock out or erroneously notify visitors!

This has a very suspicious feel to it.  If it's a legitimate site, it certainly doesn't seem to be.  Does anyone know if this is legitimate?  I want to contact the company about them linking to this site, as it may be negatively impacting other users.

Comment: Could you explain what your "suspicious feel" is based on?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a site review site.

Comment: @Anders I'm not the OP, but wondered the same.  Being redirected from the site I'm visiting to one recommending me to download something **and displaying ads** just stinks like malware stuff.
Also, I don't close my Chrome every day, but it told me "my browser is obsolete".
I got a version from oct-24 when latest stable is nov-25. This is both ridiculous and annoying.  It just makes me want to get rid of this.

Answer (score 2):

From my limited time researching the website it seems to be legitimate in respect of its intention. It offers no downloads from any source, it currently has tracking cookies Cloudflare's and a PHP session. Also, a counter js script that is going to fc.webmasterpro.de which is strange but not dangerous.

Here is the GITHUB: https://github.com/browser-update/browser-update/

It seems to have very active contributors, I would most likely assume its a new site given its new SSL cert from Cloudflare flexible certs being dated the 20th of Nov.

My verdict is don't download anything from there but otherwise, it looks safe to me.